# PHP encontrar endereços até 5km de distancia

Tags: php, mysql, geolocalização

Olá.

Estou montando um sisteminha para encontrar o prestador de serviço mais proximo do cep.

Pra isso usei a script abaixo para converter cep em coordenada.

```
$cep = "01238010";
$geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$cep.'&sensor=false');
$output= json_decode($geocode);
$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Como faço para encontrar os prestadores que estão a até 5km dessa coordenada?

Tenho um Banco de dados mysql com os ceps e coordenadas registradas dos prestadores.

Estou usando PHP e Mysql.

Obrigado!

Comment: vc vai ter q montar um logaritmo , talvez uma procedure no mysql. a conta é essa aqui . http://www.pilotopolicial.com.br/calculando-distancias-e-direcoes-utilizando-coordenadas-geograficas/

Comment: No seu banco MySQL as posições, no mapa, dos prestadores estão usando tipo de dados espacial? (POINT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use as funções espaciais do MySQL

Se o seu MySQL for versão 5.6 ou superior, por usar a função de cálculo de distância do próprio banco de dados.

Exemplo no [site do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance):

```
mysql> SET @g1 = Point(1,1);
mysql> SET @g2 = Point(2,2);
mysql> SELECT ST_Distance(@g1, @g2);
+-----------------------+
| ST_Distance(@g1, @g2) |
+-----------------------+
|    1.4142135623730951 |
+-----------------------+
```

[Nesse artigo](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-mysql-spatial-functions-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/) o autor também coloca um exemplo bem completo de como funciona.